# Pass IF statement in a concatenate variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have this statement:

```
legend = "#{post.by}"+" | #{photo.legend}"+" | #{photo.credit}"
```

If `photo.legend` is nil, I'd like the output to look like this:

```
By | Credit
```

Comment: should the string evaluate with `by` and `credit` if that returns false or not at all?

Comment: No, only if legend.present?

Comment: if `photo.legend` is nil (not present), it will return an empty string because `"#{nil}" = ""`.  You shouldn't need the if statement

Comment: Yes, but the | (pipe) still there?

Comment: if legend is nil the string will be : By | | Credit

Comment: the string I want is: **By | Credit** if legend is nil

Comment: What do you want if `photo.legend` is an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this which loops through the variables and joins together any variable that is not nil using the [Array#compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) method.

```
legend = [post.by, post.legend, photo.credit].compact.join(" | ")
```

An example:

```
[22] pry(main)> by = 'me'
=> "me"
[23] pry(main)> credit = 'some guy'
=> "some guy"
[24] pry(main)> legend = nil
=> nil
[25] pry(main)> [by, credit, legend].compact.join(" | ")
=> "me | some guy"
```

Comment: what I want is if "legend is not present" dont show the | (pipe)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
legend.split("|")[1].blank?
```

Unless I am missing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Reject and blank?

```
legend = [post.by, photo.legend, photo.credit].reject(&:blank?).join(' | ')
```

Will ouput "legend" has **By | Credit** If legend is Empty or Nil

---

```
by = post.by
legend_ph =  photo.legend
credit = photo.credit

legend = [by, credit, legend_ph].compact.join(" | ")
```

Compact will work only If is Nil

is the answer, Thanks Anthony